# how to set circular password type blink focus in edit textview in android

Tags: android

This is my edit text view code xml

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/otp_edit_box11"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_42"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_42"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_20"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_curve_bg"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberPassword"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_30"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />
```

android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor" using this i am trying show custom blink when i select edit texview

this is my curssor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="#ff000000" />

    <size android:width="100dp" />
</shape>
```

[image]

I am trying replace line blink to  password type bullet blink please help me how to  do this i tried with different  to add                 android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"

Answer (score 0):

You can use material text input layout with material text input edit text to achieve this

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
         android:id="@+id/etPassword"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="@string/password_hint"
         android:inputType="textPassword"/>
 </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```